# Where is the extra momentum?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, kinematics, momentum, conservation-laws

The question is

> A particle of charge q enters the region of uniform magnetic field B
>   (pointing into the page). The field deflects the particle a distance d
>   above the original line of flight, as shown in Figure

[image]

**So I tried using laws of kinematics but got wrong answer:**

[image]

[image]

Using

[image]

[image]

[image]

**However the solution,--------**

[image]

**has an extra term of [image]. I do understand how the author got the answer but am unable to understand why my use of kinetic equations failed.**

Comment: The magnetic force is acting perpendicular to the velocity so it can't change the magnitude of the velocity - it can only change it's direction. Also, you're using $a$ as both a distance and an acceleration - loose the kinematic equation - there is no acceleration parallel to $v$. The acceleration in this problem is radial - it's $mv^{2}/R$. Determine $R$ geometrically.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics SE.  Please, use laTex notation for formulae. It's about writing them in between of dollar symbols, and laTex commands inside. See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Check that you're trying to apply formulae from uniformly accelerated straight motion, but your movement is not straight but curvy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$t \ne \dfrac a v$ rather $t = \dfrac {\text{arc length}}{v}$

The equation $s = ut + \frac 12 a t^2$ can be written as a vector equation $(s\hat x) = t(u\hat x) + \frac 12 t^2 (a\hat x)$ where $\hat x$ is a unit vector along the x-axis.
It is a kinematic equation for constant linear acceleration $a$.
You will note that your charge does not move along a straight line.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach is that you assume the acceleration of the charge within the magnetic field is strictly along one direction. This is not true, since the acceleration is allways normal to the velocity of the charge which itself has no constant direction. Your approach would deliver a prabolic trajectory, while charges move along circles in magnetic field...